# Seeking help writing REGEX in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex that checks that in the string there is 12 | (pipes) and 13 other words any characters without | pipe ( number letters and special characters). 
the input for the regex is :

00000003 | 1 | 1 |0 | test  name | primary@email.com | Street | city | state | zip code | GBR |  description | 30

I tried to build it like this:

```
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])+(\|{1})+
([A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{}~-])
```

but the regex does not check 12 pipes. in addition, I've tried to build this regex

```
1) 
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])([\|])
(?:[^|])




2)
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])\|
(?:[^|])


3) (/|{12})
```

none of them didn't work for me. any advice?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. "Didnt work" isnt a good problem description And yes, when you have a repeating pattern, use {count} !

Comment: Any luck with my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57398911/2191572)?

Comment: Re, "any advice?" (1) Construct your regex in a browser-based regex tester. (Google for "regex tester".) it will help you to visualize which parts of your regex do or do not match which parts of your given text. (2) for complicated input, it often helps to parse it in stages or take a hybrid approach. For example: Use a simple regex to find things separated by pipe characters. Then use one or more other simple regexes to parse each thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
^([^|]+\|){12}[^|]+$
```

In English:

> Find 12 instances of anything not a pipe followed by a pipe. Then make sure it ends in something which is not a pipe

https://regex101.com/r/R8TqaL/1

Answer (score 1):

You should use this: `^(?:[^\|]+\|){12}[^\|]+$`

So properly escaped as a Java String: `String pattern = "^(?:[^\\|]+\\|){12}[^\\|]+$";`

This reads like this:

`^`: From the beginning of the expression

`(?:[^\|]+\|)`: look for a bunch of non-| followed by a | . The (?: thing is for non-capturing groups. It tells the regex engine you don't actually care about the field value, just that it's there. It's an optimization.

`{12}`: exactly 12 times

`[^\|]+`: then one last 13th field of non-|

`$`: And at that point you should reach the end of the expression

Actual example at: https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydfv274d

I'm sure you already know, but for sake of completeness, here are all the regex tokens in Java and their meanings:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include a properly escaped Java string to show it to you. I figured you'd get it from the example link I sent you. I edited the answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fit

`"^(?:[^|]*\\w[^|]*\\|){12}[^|]*\\w[^|]*$"`

https://regex101.com/r/TwYdDV/1

Explained

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?:                           # Cluster       
      [^|]* \w [^|]*                # Exists a word char
      \|                            # Pipe
 ){12}                         # End cluster, do 12 times
 [^|]* \w [^|]*                # Exists a word char
 $                             # EOS
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this one:

```
^.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*
```

[Regex explained](https://regex101.com/r/iMX4wz/1)